# Regex expression to validate an unquoted alphanumeric csv list in a attribute route regex constraint

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I'm looking for a RegEx pattern to validate an ***attribute route*** with a CSV parameter in the URL.

A valid URL would look like this (list of 0 to n elements):

```
http://site/prefix/list/a,b1,c123[,...]
```

The attribute route:

```
Route("List/{Items:alpha:regex(<pattern>)")
```

I don't have much experience with RegEx and am not having much luck with the pattern.

Comment: Why do you want to use a regex? It seems like you are trying to have the route engine parse the CSV string for you? Correct me if I'm wrong. I don't think that will work, even if it was a good idea. As far as I know, route patterns only support scalars.

Comment: @mrjoltcola, that is absolutely wrong. The csv is working perfectly in the attribute route now. I'm only looking for a way to validate it with a regex route constraint.

Comment: Ok, so I managed to misread the question twice. So I'll try once more and read literally, you say _"I'm looking for a RegEx pattern to validate an attribute route with a CSV parameter in the URL"_ - I give up, are you trying to validate the parameter, or validate the route rule itself?

Comment: Route("List/{Items:alpha:regex(<pattern>)"}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is a better approach to validate the parameter inside the action, rather than via an attribute route rule, because the route rule isn't a helpful *validator*, it won't give any feedback to the user when they enter data that doesn't match it, instead they will get an HTTP 404. But if that is indeed what you want here is an example that works for me:

Test with `http://localhost/list/movie1,movie 2,movie 3`

```
    [Route(@"list/{movieCsv:regex(^[A-Za-z0-9, ]+$)}")]
    public ActionResult ListCsv(string movieCsv)
    {
       var movies = movieCsv.Split(',');
       return View(movies);
    }
```

The View (ListCsv.cshtml):

```
   <h2>Movies</h2>
   <ul>
   @foreach (var movie in Model)
   {
     <li>@movie</li>
   }
   </ul>
```

Comment: I'm doing an attribute route.

Comment: I'm passing a list of undetermined length made up of alphanumeric symbols. It's a list of game titles. Like "FooBar, Foo at Bar, Bar, The Longest Title You Can Think Of, Something 10, Something Else,Ad Nauseam" There is no pattern to the names themselves. Just a comma separated list of unquoted alphanumeric strings.

Comment: See my revised answer. Uses a single parameter, and splits within the  action.

Comment: I am having no trouble consuming the CSV that is done and working. I only want to validate the URL using the Route attribute.

Comment: Revised. Accepts spaces and commas and alphanumeric.